# Рекурсивный обход папок

Tags: c, файлы, рекурсия, segmentation-fault

Задана иерархия папок и файлов по следующим правилам:

1) название папок может быть только "add" или "mul"

2) В папках могут находиться другие вложенные папки и/или текстовые файлы

3)Текстовые файлы имеют произвольное имя с расширением .txt

4)Содержимое текстовых файлов представляет собой строку, в которой через пробел записано некоторое количество целых чисел

Требуется написать программу, которая, запускается в корневой директории, содержащей одну папку с именем "add" или "mul" и вычисляет и выводит на экран результат выражения состоящего из чисел в поддиректориях по следующим правилам:

1)Если в папке находится один или несколько текстовых файлов, то математическая операция определяемая названием папки (add = сложение, mul = умножение) применяется ко всем числам всех файлов в этой папке

2)Если в папке находится еще одна или несколько папок, то сначала вычисляются значения выражений, определяемые ими, а после используются уже эти значения

Написал программу, но иногда при большом кол-ве папок и файлов вылетает segmentation fault. С чем это связано?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


long long int counter(const char* dirPath, char* lastDir){
    printf("%s\n", dirPath);
    long long int tmp;
    long long int res = 0;
    char* dirCopy;
    DIR *dir = opendir(dirPath);
    if (strcmp(lastDir, "add") == 0){
        res = 0;
        struct  dirent *de = readdir(dir);
        while (de){
            if (strcmp(de->d_name, "add") == 0){
                dirCopy = (char*)malloc((strlen(dirPath) + 5) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(dirCopy, dirPath);
                strcat(dirCopy, "/");
                strcat(dirCopy, "add");
                res += counter(dirCopy, "add");
            }
            else if(strcmp(de->d_name, "mul") == 0){
                dirCopy = (char*)malloc((strlen(dirPath) + 5) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(dirCopy, dirPath);
                strcat(dirCopy, "/");
                strcat(dirCopy, "mul");
                res += counter(dirCopy, "mul");
            }
            else if(strstr(de->d_name, ".txt") != NULL){
                dirCopy = (char*)malloc((strlen(dirPath) + strlen(de->d_name) + 2) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(dirCopy, dirPath);
                strcat(dirCopy, "/");
                strcat(dirCopy, de->d_name);
                FILE* file = fopen(dirCopy, "r");
                while(fscanf(file, "%lld", &tmp) != EOF){
                    printf("%lld\n", tmp);
                    res += tmp;
                }
            }
                    de = readdir(dir);
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp(lastDir, "mul") == 0){
        res = 1;
        struct  dirent *de = readdir(dir);
        while (de){
            if (strcmp(de->d_name, "add") == 0){
                dirCopy = (char*)malloc((strlen(dirPath) + 5) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(dirCopy, dirPath);
                strcat(dirCopy, "/");
                strcat(dirCopy, "add");
                res *= counter(dirCopy, "add");
            }
            else if(strcmp(de->d_name, "mul") == 0){
                strcpy(dirCopy, dirPath);
                strcat(dirCopy, "/");
                strcat(dirCopy, "mul");
                res *= counter(dirCopy, "mul");
            }
            else if(strstr(de->d_name, ".txt") != NULL){
                dirCopy = (char*)malloc((strlen(dirPath) + strlen(de->d_name) + 2) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(dirCopy, dirPath);
                strcat(dirCopy, "/");
                strcat(dirCopy, de->d_name);
                FILE* file = fopen(dirCopy, "r");
                while(fscanf(file, "%lld", &tmp) != EOF){
                    printf("%lld\n", tmp);
                    res *= tmp;
                }
            }
            de = readdir(dir);
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp(lastDir, "tmp") == 0){
        if(dir) {
            res = 0;
                struct  dirent *de = readdir(dir);
                while (de) {
                    if (strcmp(de->d_name, "add") == 0){
                    dirCopy = (char*)malloc((strlen(dirPath) + 5) * sizeof(char));
                    strcpy(dirCopy, dirPath);
                    strcat(dirCopy, "/");
                    strcat(dirCopy, "add");
                    res += counter(dirCopy, "add");
                }
                else if(strcmp(de->d_name, "mul") == 0){
                    dirCopy = (char*)malloc((strlen(dirPath) + 5) * sizeof(char));
                    strcpy(dirCopy, dirPath);
                    strcat(dirCopy, "/");
                    strcat(dirCopy, "mul");
                    res += counter(dirCopy, "mul");
                }
                        de = readdir(dir);
                }
            }
    }
    return res;
}




int main(){
    char* path = (char*)malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    long long int c;
    FILE* file_ptr;
    strcpy(path,"tmp");
    c = counter(path, "tmp");
    file_ptr = fopen("result.txt", "w");
    fprintf(file_ptr, "%lld", c);
}
```

Comment: Для того, что бы узнать, в чем именно проблема и что вызывает ошибку сегментирования лучше всего использовать отладчик. Но, скорее всего, Вы не проверяете корректность вызова какой-либо функции: например, открыли Вы файл, но не проверили, что он действительно открылся и пытаетесь из него что-либо прочитать.

Answer (score 1):

I. После вызова `opendir` нужно проверять на ошибки. Если вернётся `NULL` может быть всё что угодно. Например errno = `ENOTDIR` - означает что файл - НЕ директория. Или даже `EACCESS` - нет доступа.

II. После каждого окончания цикла для просмотра директории нужно вызвать `closedir(dir)`.

III. Переменной `dirCopy` в каждом участке с `malloc` нужно занятую память удалить с помощью `free`.